# Cross browser keydown handling of carriage return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm looking for a cross browser solution to handling carriage return, to submit input from a text box.

My current issue is firefox...

javascript event is not defined

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" onkeydown="press();" value="X"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function press() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // do something
    }
}
<script>
```

I can use jquery.

Comment: If you can use jQuery you should use it to attach the event handlers as well, rather than using inline attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where does `event` come from? :-)

Here is the solution you're looking for:

```
// First, change the HTML to:
<input id="myinput" type="text" onkeydown="return press( event );" value="X" />

// Then, on the JS part:
function press( e ) {
    var evt = e || window.event
    // "e" is the standard behavior (FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera),
    // while "window.event" (or "event") is IE's behavior
    if ( evt.keyCode === 13 ) {
        // Do something

        // You can disable the form submission this way:
        return false
    }
}
```

Note the use of `return` in this function and the HTML event to prevent the form from submitting (which is the default behavior when you press [Enter] in a form's field).

However, I'd recommend removing the javascript part in the HTML, and go straight with:

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onkeydown = function( e ) {
    // Your code
}
```

This allows you to have [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

For the jQuery way, this'd be the following:

```
$('#myinput').on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
    // jQuery normalizes the "e" parameter, so you can use:
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        // Do something
    }
} )
```

P.S.: `event` is actually the same as `window.event`, which is the correct use for IE. This is not the standard though, which other browsers (FF, Chrome...) use. Which is why we use the trick provided (`var evt = e || window.event`, where `e` was passed as argument).

Comment: +1 great answer, but could be more complete. (missing definition of function argument in HTML `onkeydown` attribute; suggest using `return false` to disable browsers default behaviour)

Comment: FTFY, it was still missing the `return` in the `onkeydown` HTML attribute. (`return false` from the function will be ignored otherwise)

Comment: In fact, it is. Your jsfille example is not useful as it does not contain a form or input field at all. Try http://jsfiddle.net/tAFbT/ (without return) vs http://jsfiddle.net/tAFbT/1/ (with additional return). Press enter in the input field and you will see: without return, the content box loads the index page. With additional return nothing happens. (the form submit is cancelled)

Comment: also, with plain javascript the argument passed to the event handler must be named "event", at least for firefox. fixed that too. ;-)

Comment: Oh well, I guess I learn everyday :-) Thanks for all this information!

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you must define `event` for the use in FF/Chrome/Opera/.. in the function definition **and** in the function call. (`onkeydown`)

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
<input id="myinput" type="text" onkeydown="return press( event )" value="X"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function press(e) {
    // IE uses "window.event", others pass the event as argument
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        // do something
        alert("enter!");

        return false;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `return` in both the function definition **and** the function call in the HTML markup. It **prevents the form from submitting**, which is the *default behaviour when you hit enter* in an input inside a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myinput').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
         //do something.
         e.preventDefault();
       }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the event parameter that will be passed to your function:

```
function press(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work on IE, you need to do `var e = event || window.event` in your case :)